# How to get connection string from appsettings.json in a .net 6 worker service?

Tags: c#, service, configuration, .net-6.0

I use the code below.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using WorkerService;
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
   
    services.Configure<WorkerService.DAL._DBConnStr>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
   
})
.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

The connection string in appsettings.json like this.

```
    {
 "Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"sqlserver1ConnectionString": "...",
"oracle1ConnectionString": "...",
..............

  }
}
```

There is an error in  `services.Configure<WorkerService.DAL._DBConnStr>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));`

"Configuration" doesn't exit.

How to reslove it?

Comment: Please share full JSON, it's hard to tell what's the structure of it. Also did you specified in code that config should be read for this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) overload accepting action with two parameters - `HostBuilderContext` and `IServiceCollection`, and use `HostBuilderContext` to access the configuration:

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
    {  
        services.Configure<WorkerService.DAL._DBConnStr>(ctx.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        // ...
    })
```

Comment: Thank you ,it works.Can you explain it?

Comment: @A.K what exactly needs to be explained?

Comment: the parameter (ctx, services)

Comment: @A.K `ConfigureServices` accepts an `Action<HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection>` which is [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) representing function with two parameters. In this case it is passed as anonymous function ([lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)). Basically it is the same as the one you've used but with one more parameter.